# Multiplying vowels in a string

Tags: python

I'm attempting to take a string as input and return that same string with each vowel multiplied by 4 and a "!" added at the end. Ex. 'hello' returns, 'heeeelloooo!'

```
def exclamation(s):
'string ==> string, returns the string with every vowel repeating four times and an exclamation mark at the end'
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
res = ''
for a in s:
    if a in vowels:
        return s.replace(a, a * 4) + '!'
```

The above code just returns 'heeeello!' I also attempted it in the interactive shell with vowels equaling ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') but using the same code resulted in this:

```
>>> for a in s:
if a in vowels:
    s.replace(a, a * 4) + '!'
```

'heeeello!'
'helloooo!'

How can I get it to multiply each vowel and not just one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is, you're looping over the string, and if the character is a vowel, you're replacing that vowel in the string with four of it and then stopping. That's not what you want to do. Instead, loop over the vowels and replace the vowel in the string, assigning the result back to the input string. When you're done, return the resulting string with an exclamation mark appended.

```
def exclamation(s):
    'string ==> string, returns the string with every vowel repeating four times and an exclamation mark at the end'
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    for vowel in vowels:
        s = s.replace(vowel, vowel * 4)
    return s + '!'
```

Comment: Thank you! I now see what I was doing wrong. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

I would personally use a regexp here:

```
import re

def f(text):
    return re.sub(r'[aeiou]', lambda L: L.group() * 4, text, flags=re.I) + '!'

print f('hello')
# heeeelloooo!
```

This has the advantage of scanning the string only once. (And IMHO is fairly readable as to what it's doing).

Comment: I'm still fairly new to python so it's pretty advanced for me. It does work but I don't really understand how yet (maybe in the future I will.) Thank you very much for the help either way!

Comment: The item `r'[aeiou]'` means for any vowel, and the `lambda` expression means to take whatever matched the regex, and replace it with 4 times that string.  Finally, the flag `re.I` tells regex to ignore the case (so `'A'` would match too).

Comment: Oh I see. This and looking it up in the docs made it make more sense. So does the L in "lambda L: L.group()" have any significance or was it just a variable?

Comment: @iKyriaki `re.sub` can take a callable object instead of a text replacement, `lambda` defines a callable that's passed the match object, and returns `L.group() * 4`. (It's a single line statement that can be used instead of `def some_func(match): return match.group() * 4`)

Comment: @iKyriaki I'd still with what you've got at the moment, and bear this in mind for future reference :)

Comment: How about: `re.sub(r'([aeiou])', r'\1' * 4, text, flags=re.I)` ?